# Size or number of elements in an array of objects? in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, object

Ex.
Student[] storage = new Student[10]; 
After initialization, is there a method or anything i can do to return the # of objects created besides setting a counter?

Comment: `storage.length` .....

Comment: Number of what objects? What do yoylu think the method would do behind the scenes?

Comment: @Square-root Can you elaborate when you say "Counter", do you mean counter in a loop or in the constructor?

Comment: You set a global counter to zero. Then each time an object is initialized the counter increases. either in a loop or a constructor

Comment: Not with that line of code, you don't.

Comment: I mean how do you do it later in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an array, the array size is fixed, so storage.length will always give you the array size. You will end up doing this to get number of instantiated objects:

```
for(Student s : storage){
    if (s != null)
        count ++;
}
```

**1st Approach:**

However, if you store the created objects within a **list**. You can simply get the number of objects by: `list.size();`

```
ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
list.add(new Student("Alice"));
list.add(new Student("Bob"));
```

**2nd Approach:**

You can also make a count in the class itself.

```
class Student{
    private static int studCreated = 0;

    public Student(){
        studCreated ++;   //Counts automatically
    }
    //Other constructors not shown here

    public static int getStudCreated(){
        return studCreated;
    }
}
```

Everytime a new Student object gets instantiated, the Student constructor will be called, hence automatically update the number of objects created.

```
new Student("Alice");
new Student("Bob");
new Student("Carol");
System.out.println(Student.getStudCreated());  //Print num of Student obj instantiated.
```

3 will be printed, since constructor was called 3 times.

Comment: In the second approach the increment should be in a synchronized block on `Student.class`, just to be safe.

Comment: if you mean vote up, i did it but it says i gotta have at least a total of 15 reputation which i don't have yet

Comment: @Square-root Not upvote, you can still accept a solution by clicking the hollow looking [tick](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) below the upvote button. you gain 2 rep in return. It doesn't matter how much rep you have currently.